# Returning method for Fahrenheit to Celcius and non returning for Celcius to Fahrenheit

Tags: java, return

```
package tempconverter;

import java.util.*;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class TempConverter {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double tem;

        System.out.print("Enter number: ");
        double temp = sc.nextDouble();    
        System.out.println("Convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit (C or F): ");
        int input = sc.nextInt();

        if (input == 'C'){
            System.out.println("Fahrenheit to Celcius is: " + toCelsius(temp));
        }else if(input == 'F'){
            toFahrenheit(temp);
        } 
        public static double toCelsius(double cels){
            double far = 5/9.0*(cels-32);
            return far;
        }
        public static void toFahrenheit(double fahr){
            double tem = 9/5.0*fahr+32;
            System.out.println("Celsius to Fahrenheit: " + toFahrenheit(tem));
    }
}
```

Comment: `toFahrenheit` doesn't return anything and has a declared return type of `void`. Look at how that's different from `toCelsius`.

Comment: Also `C or F` won't match `nextInt()`

Comment: Questions are much better if they are accompanied by some explanatory text. "Help please" is not explanatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I refactored your code. You were having a recursive call inside one of your methods and your method were not returning values.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String name = null;
        float temperature;
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter temperature: " );
        temperature = in.nextFloat();

        System.out.println("Convert to Celsius or Fahrenheit (C or F): ");
        name = in.next();


        if (name.equals("C")) {
            System.out.println("Fahrenheit to Celcius: " + toCelsius(temperature));
        }else if (name.equals("F")){
            System.out.println("Celsius to Fahrenheit: " + toFahrenheit(temperature));
        }

    }

public static double toCelsius(double cels){
        double far = 5/9.0*(cels-32);
        return far;
    }
    public static double toFahrenheit(double fahr){
        double tem = 9/5.0*fahr+32;
        return tem;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help sir :D

Comment: if (name.equals("C")) {
            System.out.println("Fahrenheit to Celcius: " + toCelsius(temperature));
        }else if (name.equals("F")){
            toFahrenheit(temperature);
        }

    }

public static double toCelsius(double cels){
        double far = 5/9.0*(cels-32);
        return far;
    }
    public static void toFahrenheit(double fahr){
        double tem = 9/5.0*fahr+32;
        System.out.println("Celsius to Fahrenheit: " + tem);
    }
}

Comment: You need to keep the code consistent and return a value on both methods. Otherwise it will hard to read/maintain. Do you mind marking the answer as accepted if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem is that you have a cycle in your code. The method toFahrenheit calls toFahrenheit again inside the println. This leads to an infinite loop which will result in a stackoverflow at some point. Move the println outside of the method like in the toCelsius and return the converted value.

Apart from this you have a problem as 'C' and 'F'.

Comment: Thank you for the info sir, this could help :D